# Shorter expression of a special conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ be a set and $B$ a condition (can be either true or false). Is there any shorter description of the expression
$$
x = \begin{cases}
A & B \\
\emptyset & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \text{?}
$$
An inline solution would be nice.

One possibility is to define
$$
\text{cond}(A, B) =
\begin{cases}
A & B \\
\emptyset & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and set $x = \text{cond}(A, B)$. But is there a more "intuitive" way to do this without defining a new function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $\{ x\ \lvert\ x \in A \wedge B \}$ or $\{ x \in A\ \lvert\ B \}$? I would personally stick to your original approach, though.

Comment: Okay, nice idea. I just wait before I mark it as answer. Maybe there is a more "intuitive" way.